# Is there a way to creat a python code to read the description under the links of google search as a text?

Tags: python

I read a lot about the libraries that I should install to use to print the URL links or to open a web link but I got confused a lot about what I should do or install as they are not meet my need.
I need a way that if I enter a sentence to search, it prints me in the output the descriptions that appear under the URLs as a string:
like in this picture:[example of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1GUE.png)

I use IDLE (python 3.9 64-bit ).

Comment: Why do you think they do not meet your need?  If you can see it, then it's on the web page.  In this case, the page is probably not even dynamic, so `requests` and `beautifulsoup` should do what you need.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? If you want to get results from Google Search then you can try to use `requests` + `beautifulsoup`. But Google may use JavaScript to generate page and to detect scripts/bots/spamers and block them (using ReCaptcha) then better can be to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web broswer. And it also has functions to get any element from displayed HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code which uses [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser.

First it open browser and load page `google.com`.
Next it closes popup dialog which ask for cookies.
Next it fills search field and click `ENTER`.
And finally it gets all `<div>` with `class="g"` and search all `<span>` which may have text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

query = 'what is the sound of elephant'

url = 'https://google.com/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

# --- close popup dialog ---

items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[div[@role]]')
items[1].click()

time.sleep(2)

# --- fill input ---

items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@maxlength]')
items[0].send_keys(query + Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(2)

# --- get results ---

items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="g"]')  # absolute xpath 
print('len(items):', len(items))

for item_number, item in enumerate(items):
    print('\n--- item:', item_number, '---\n')
    spans = item.find_elements_by_xpath('./div/div/div/div/span')  # relative xpath
    for number, s in enumerate(spans):
        print('- span:', number, '-')
        print(s.text.strip())
```

Results:

Because Google can detect my language's settings in web browser (Polish) so some results are in Polish (ie. date)

```
len(items): 10

--- item: 0 ---


--- item: 1 ---


--- item: 2 ---


--- item: 3 ---


--- item: 4 ---

- span: 0 -
Trumpeting is the most famous and recognisable sound from an elephant's vocabulary, its high-pitched tone heard for miles around. However, ...
- span: 1 -
Przesłany przez: Kim Schnarr

--- item: 5 ---

- span: 0 -
What sounds do elephants make? · Trumpeting · Rumbling · Roaring · Chirps and Squeaks · Ear Flapping · Bubbling.

--- item: 6 ---

- span: 0 -
6 paź 2017 —
- span: 1 -
Elephants like this African forest elephant make trumpeting sounds when they are excited, fearful, or happy. ... Please be respectful of copyright.

--- item: 7 ---

- span: 0 -
The range of sounds elephants produce ... African elephants produce a broad range of sounds from very low frequency Rumbles to higher frequency Snorts, Barks, ...

--- item: 8 ---

- span: 0 -
12 sie 2015 —
- span: 1 -
Elephants make a sound, known as a trumpet, to signal excitement, aggression and distress. This trumpeting can be heard from up to six miles ...

--- item: 9 ---

- span: 0 -
30 gru 2016 —
- span: 1 -
Scott Pettit: Elephants don't say anything. They trumpet. So you have to verbally interpret a trumpeting sound. “Pawoooo” isn't too bad, actually.
```